# Integrating layer-atlas in my android studio project

Tags: java, android

While integrating layer-atlus, I am getting following error.
[Layer Atlas documentation link](https://developer.layer.com/docs/atlas/android)

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see strange is that you are compiling using java 1.8. Check that.

And the second issue could be caused by famous [android method limit](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

I suggest to pick a specific google play services dependency instead of all-in-one and if even that is not enough, go for multidex solution.